# Why I don't have permission of reading of my project after configurate Apache in OSX Maverick?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I was installing apache and I followed the following [guide](http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-install-apache-and-php-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-1/) to configure it.

This is what I tried:

1.Create folder

```
mkdir ~Sites
```

2.Current user

```
whoami
```

return **zhelon**

3.Create a file .conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/users/zhelon.conf
```

4.Insert this code

`<Directory "/Usuarios/zhelon/Sites/">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>`

5.Modicate the httpd.conf

`AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`

6.Delete `#` from to `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

7.`sudo apachectl restart`

8.Create `phpinfo.php` inside `Site` with:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

My problem show when I write `http://localhost/~zhelon/phpinfo.php` in my browser because this appears

`You don't have permission to access /~zhelon/phpinfo.php on this server.`

If I do `ls -l` it returns this:

`drwxr-xr-x   4 zhelon  staff   136 Aug 26 23:30 Sites`

How can I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant Apache access to your home directory (`/usarios/zhelon`) as well. Granting it access to `~/Sites` isn't enough - it'd be like putting a "free, take one" display inside a locked bank vault.

Comment: Do you talk about at the time of creating the folder in the terminal?

Comment: no. permissions on your home directory. `ls -ld /Usarios/zhelon` will show you what they are. unless it's 755 or whatever, apache can't get in there.

Comment: ``drwxr-xr-x+ 32 zhelon  staff  1088 Aug 26 23:02 /Users/zhelon``

Comment: any option if apache cant get in??

Comment: the `+` indicates there's an ACL on that directory, above/beyond the standard unix permissions. `ls -le` would list those.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need world read and execute permissions on your home directory and the phpinfo.php file as well.

To do that:

```
chmod 755 /Usuarios/zhelon
chmod 755 /Usuarios/zhelon/phpinfo.php
```

Comment: ``drwxr-xr-x   4 zhelon  staff   136 Aug 26 23:30 Sites``, I dont know how see the zhelon's permissions

Comment: ``drwxr-xr-x+ 32 zhelon  staff  1088 Aug 26 23:02 /Users/zhelon``